# php stop quote escape

Tags: php, apache

I have a small php code that prints welcome message

```
<?php
echo "Hello ". $_GET['name'];
?>
```

I've put this code on my website hosted on Godaddy's server and I found that the server is escaping the single and double quotes. For example

```
http://www.example.com/test.php?name=test's
```

prints

```
Hello test\'s
```

but the same code runs fine on apache server on my PC. How can this be fixed?

Comment: worst web host ever, move now if you know what's good for you.

Comment: I wish I could upvote comments more than once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the next code in a `.htaccess` file to inform PHP that [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) shouldn't be added to **G**ET, **P**OST and **C**ookie variables.

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

If your webhost does not allow you to change your settings, your need to remove these quotes yourself using the `stripslashes` function. Since the `$_GET` / `$_POST` / `$_COOKIE` array may contain other arrays (by using field names like `name[full]=John Smit`), you need a recursive function to strip the slashes. For example, use the snippet from [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php#99183) to remove all "magic quotes" from the input:

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $strip_slashes_deep = function ($value) use (&$strip_slashes_deep) {
        return is_array($value) ? array_map($strip_slashes_deep, $value) : stripslashes($value);
    };
    $_GET = array_map($strip_slashes_deep, $_GET);
    $_POST = array_map($strip_slashes_deep, $_POST);
    $_COOKIE = array_map($strip_slashes_deep, $_COOKIE);
}
?>
```

Note that your code snippet is vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), so use [proper escaping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
<?php
echo "Hello " . htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']);
?>
```

Another recommended way to retrieve such input values are the `filter_*` functions. Example which is the equivalent of the above snippet, but works regardless of the `magic_quotes_gpc` setting:

```
<?php
echo filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
?>
```

Related documentation:

- [function `filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)
- [Sanitize filters for filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Answer (score 4):

Godaddy apparently has magic quotes enabled:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    echo stripslashes($_GET['name']);
else
    echo $_GET['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Urlencode your querystring before submitting it, and then use urldecode before writing it back out to the browser. This will mitigate any browser or hosting issues and is good practice. What you are doing is generally considered to be a 'bad idea', because apostrophes and quotes are not directly supported in URLs without encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using godaddy, I recommend you call `stripslashes`:

```
<?php
echo "Hello ". stripslashes($_GET['name']);
?>
```